# RegEx Match pattern unless escaped

Tags: php, regex

I tried a few flavours of `PHP` markdown converter for converting *XYZ* into <em> tags, and **ABC** into <strong> tags. They were doing a bit too much for what I needed like adding paragraph tags, etc.

*Note that I'm only using two markdown tags*.

I wrote a RegExp which works okay, but I needed to escape the reserved characters incase the user wants a literal one of those characters, like I had to in my post.

This is what I have so far:

```
preg_replace("/(?<!\\\)\*\*([^\*\*]*)(?<!\\\)\*\*/", "<strong>$1</strong>", $line);
```

For those reading in the future that do not know RegEx too well, `(?<!\\\)` means don't match the following pattern if it is preceded by a backslash. `([^\*]*)` is equivalent to `.*` but safer in that it says match everything until we get a double asterisk. The parens mean collect this answer so that I can use it as $1 in the next section

It breaks when I do 'My name is **Earle\***'. I would like it to output

```
My name is <strong>Earle*</strong>
```

But it outputs

```
My name is <em></em>Earle<em></em>*
```

What is wrong with my RegEx, and can you explain what the fixes are so that people in future know

Comment: It's not possible that `<strong>$1</strong>` will be changed to `<em>Earle</em>`. You are not showing some code for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match escaped entities, you cannot use lookarounds for that.

```
\*\*([^*\\]*(?:\\.[^\\*]*)*)\*\*
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qO7zG6/1)

**Explanation**:

- `\*\*` - 2 leading asterisks
- `([^*\\]*(?:\\.[^\\*]*)*)` - Group 1 matching

  - `[^*\\]*` - zero or more characters other than `*` and `\`
  - `(?:\\.[^\\*]*)*` - zero or more sequences of...

    - `\\.` - any escape sequence
    - `[^\\*]*` - zero or more characters other than `*` and `\`
- `\*\*` - 2 trailing asterisks

The regex is based on the unroll-the-loop principle and should be efficient enough to work with any texts.

Also, you can use `/s` modifier to even support an escaped newline.